# Replace Formula With Cell Value PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Similar to these documentations.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-a-formula-with-its-result-32a9675c-45f0-4a15-b130-d55356437c86 (For Mac) 
And 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-a-formula-with-its-result-38001951-c0e8-4fbd-9048-37ef81e2891e (For Windows)

Can we replace a Formula with the cell Value using PHPExcel.

For example: Given Cell 'A1' that contains Formula "='Sheet1'!L2". The formula equates to 1. 
Is there a way to replace the function to hold '1' and erase the input formula with PHPExcel?

If not, that would be really handy for optimization, and to remove the excessive problems that arise from ->getOldCalculatedValue/getCalculatedValue/->setPreCalculateFormulas().

Thanks

Comment: So by replicating the 'CMD+=' we can save loads of time. So Cell A1 contains formula. We do $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->FormulaValue();     We would take the cell content without calculation and replace it in the formula bar replicating the 'CMD+='. That would be great.!

Comment: Sorry, in english please.... what is this `FormulaValue()` method? What does it do? Where does it come from?

Comment: And there's nothing to stop you writing code that prefixes any raw formula with `CMD+=` now: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'A1',
        'CMD+' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getCell('A1')
            ->getValue()
    );` I just fail to see what it will achieve

Comment: Hey Mark. In english. This FormulaValue() is still not developed. When it is done being developed, with this PHPExcel extension, the FormulaValue() method, would take the cell value as a text and replace the formula in the formula bar with the cell value text. So it would over ride the existing formula with the cell value. Dont you think it would be great and usable ?

Comment: What I can't see is where the cell value comes from? If you have a cell that contains a formula `=1+2`, how does this magical `FormulaValue()` method know to replace that with `3`?

Comment: The whole concept is, PHPExcel is a really great library. I personally love it. I work in Insurance and have been using it excessively. Now the only problem is when we have a 20 sheet INTENSE formulated workbook. When we ->getCalculatedValue() of a cell, it has to calculate ALL the values of all the functions that reference this cell, which takes loads of time. With this method it will take the cell value AS IS without calculating it and replaces the formula with that. In that case one can call FormulaValue() and get the cell text directly without calculation

Comment: What is this "cell text"? The content of the cell, read from the file is the formula `=1+2`

Comment: Well thats exactly what im going to try to do. Try to catch the 3 as a 3 not a calculated value.

Comment: But the MS Excel file holds the formula, not the actual result. The closest is the "old calculated value" (which PHPExcel provides access to via the `getOldCalculatedValue()` method..... but that can be wrong, or may not even exist in the file, so that can't be trusted

Comment: Yes, i personally dont use getOldCalculatedValue() since it hasnt gave me a 100% result success rate. So basically when Excel Saves we calculate all values and save a file that holds all the cells instances as the actual results and not values. So when one loads an excel file and calls the FormulaValue() or optimized getOldCalculatedValue() , it will return the actual stored value and not the formula. If they however want to work with getCalculated and getFormatted nothing will change. Ill try to make it so that the FormulaValue only works post PHPExcel->Save

Comment: I know that setPreCalculateFormulas(True) might help around with that, but i personally dont like that function aswell, it takes LOADS of time with a 20+ sheet workbook. Around 4-5 mins to save.

Answer (score 0):

Logically

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'A1',
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getCell('A1')
            ->getCalculatedValue()
    );
```

Though I fail to see how it can optimize anything, because you still have to calculate the formula to get the value anyway

Comment: Hello Mark. Well yes, but in my case cell A1 for example holds a value correctly. After i save using PHPExcel getCalculatedValue Throws the catch exception and getOldCalculatedValue returns 0. Ive read all your comments on setting setPreCalculateFormulas(). But my code returns with a  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Data!I1 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GenRe/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:300 Stack trace: #0 and Data!I1 is a string not a formula.

Comment: So if we can keep the excel file with the cell containing the correct value for example 1 for cell A1 and then write code to force that cell to replace formula with the 1 value. Then no errors will arise in many cases. That way we wouldve IGNORED the getCalculatedValue function. Dont you think?

Comment: Unless PHPExcel can calculate the formula itself to get the value, then there's no real alternative. `getOldCalculatedValue()` isn't trustworthy, there are too many ways in which that value can be wrong (or not even exist) for it to be anything more than an emergency fallback..... if you absolutely have to do this replacement; then `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'A1',
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getCell('A1')
            ->getOldCalculatedValue()
    );` but be warned that `getOldCalculatedValue()` may not always return a correct value

Comment: Ye it isnt, it returns a 0. Ill try to fiddle around with a ->FormulaValue function and see if i can manage to do what i asked. Ill keep you posted.Thanks anyways